# Are semicolons WITH spaces allowed as a delimiter for an Active Directory DirectoryString attribute value?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a third-party web app that is running a LDAP query to find if a user's email address exists in AD.  The query looks like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(proxyAddresses=SMTP:foouser@example.co.uk))
```

My `proxyAddresses` attribute value in AD looks like this:

```
X500:/o=foo/ou=foo Group (ABC123)/cn=Foo3/cn=foouser (blah)123; SIP:foouser@example.co.uk; smtp:foouser@sub1.example.co.uk; smtp:foouser@sub2.example.co.uk; SMTP:foouser@example.co.uk
```

The web app is getting empty results back.  I see a similar result when I check with AD Explorer.  Also, when I look at the raw output in AD Explorer, it puts the entire attribute value on a single line instead of showing each SMTP and X500 entry on a separate line.

All of this makes me think that the value may not be delimited properly.

When I compared the attribute with another environment, the other environment didn't have spaces between the values.

For example... mine:

```
X500:/o=foo/ou=foo Group (ABC123)/cn=Foo3/cn=foouser (blah)123; SIP:foouser@example.co.uk; smtp:foouser@sub1.example.co.uk; smtp:foouser@sub2.example.co.uk; SMTP:foouser@example.co.uk
```

The other environment:

```
X500:/o=foo/ou=foo Group (ABC123)/cn=Foo3/cn=foouser (blah)123;SIP:foouser@example.co.uk;smtp:foouser@sub1.example.co.uk;smtp:foouser@sub2.example.co.uk;SMTP:foouser@example.co.uk
```

So my question is:

**Are semicolons WITH spaces allowed as a delimiter for an Active Directory DirectoryString attribute value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a query point of view, the delimiter is really just a cosmetic display option for presenting the data. Different tools will display the multiple values in different ways. Make sure you are using the same version of the same tool in both environments.

The `attributes` tab in `DSA.MSC` uses semi colons with spaces, but open that attribute to edit with DSA and you get a list with each attribute on a new line. Some other methods you can you to query and display: `CSVDE` will generate a file that uses semi colons. `Get-Aduser` will use ", " in the general query, but then use newlines when you expand the attribute.

```
csvde -r "(samaccountname=roadRunner)" -f this.csv -l proxyaddresses
get-aduser -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=roadRunner)" -prop proxyaddresses
(get-aduser -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=roadRunner)" -prop proxyaddresses).proxyaddresses
```

Is the user found when you run the same query with? `get-aduser -ldapfilter "(&(objectClass=user)(proxyAddresses=SMTP:foouser@example.co.uk))"`

Comment: Closing the loop on this.  Both answers on this post are correct.  Upon examining the attribute with ADSIEDIT, we could clearly see that it had a single entry with all of the data entered in it (but semicolon delimited in THAT input). Thus, it looked very similar when reviewing output with on ADExplorer. The telltale sign was that the `count` column for ADExplorer showed "1" for the entry.  I should have caught that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such thing a a delimiter or separator for multivalued attributes.

If you import or export data using ldif files the format looks like this:

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
dc: example
description: This is the first description value
description: This is the second description value
```

And if I query my account using the standard dsquery tool I get this format as well

```
dsquery * "cn=my user name,ou=whatever,dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=tld" -scope base -attr * | findstr /i 
proxyAddresses: smtp:aaa@bbb.cd
proxyAddresses: SMTP: AAA@bbbb.cccc
...
```

Using ldapsearch from a linux host gives me the same ldif format. So my guess is that the the application is not parsing the result of the filter correctly, it should be looping through the returned list of values. If it does not, then it looks to me like there is a bug in their code.

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679424(v=vs.85).aspx#win_8_server) the Proxy-Addresses attribute is not single valued, and its syntax is [string unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684455(v=vs.85).aspx). Additionaly, msdn has a small entry about the differences between single and multivalued attributes [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746488(v=vs.85).aspx), but it does not say anything about delimiters or formats (only that entries may not be empty).

Comment: Thanks.  What's strange is that TWO applications are displaying the results oddly (including Microsoft's own sysinternals tool).  That's what makes me think something isn't formatted right.

Comment: the sysinternals tools are awesome, but they are not official MS tools. You need standard ldap tools to reproduce the problem (ldp.exe, adsiedit.msc, even the attribute editor of ADUC could be useful, it shows multivalued attributes in different lines if I recall properly - you need to enable the advanced view first)

Comment: Arguably, SysInternals tools *are* official MS tools because MS has owned the company since 2006 and distributed many updated versions and tools since then under the SysInternals moniker. Mark Russinovich is currently the CTO of MS Azure.

Comment: good luck convincing MS to give you support with that kind of reasoning ;-) (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/license-faq, last paragraph)